# Will there be any sudden shooting of memory after killing the process and starting it

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, jmeter

I request help to clarify my doubt on the following case.

i am currently performing performance test for my application using jmeter and one thing i noticed was when i killed the service of the appliction from the task manager and do load testing with 1000 users the memory usage is getting boosted from 200 MB to 900 MB and then returning to  200-300 mb range.Just would like to know whether this is a performance issue with application

Comment: Some help on this please

Comment: There can be a performance issue with application if you kill it, can you add more details? is it non gui? what is inside test plan?

Comment: Thank you for you reply,Heres what the problem is,i wanted to confirm whether the following behaviour is a general behaviour in all application.

a.) I killed the service on which the application runs from the  task manager.
b.) Then i run jmeter for login into application with 1000 users
c.)I was then able to observer that there was a sudden increase in memory upto 900 MB and then in a moment later it is getting dropped and reach 200-250 MB
d.)again when i perform with 1000 user i am not seeing such rise
e.)only when i kill the process and do a load test do i see the rise